# Plotting Archimedes's spiral

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help to plot the following Arhimede's spiral, which in polar coordinates has the equation

```
r=t, t\in [0,4*pi]
```

I used the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle, xtick={2},ytick={2},
no marks,axis equal,xmin=-20,xmax=20,ymin=-20,ymin=20,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
          \addplot[no markers,samples=101, domain=0:8*pi,variable=\t]({(\t)*cos(\t r)}, {(\t)*sin(\t r)});
        \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But the output is far from the desired plotting. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Just replace the second `ymin=20` by `ymax=20` and use `samples=1001` to make it a bit smoother.

Comment: Also, if you add in the plot `\addplot[data cs=polar, ...] ` you can write the coordinates directly in polar coordinates. `(\t r, \t)`, which might make it simpler as well

Comment: @Sergei Golovan & Alex Recuenco Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're loading the `polar` library, so I presume you'd like to have a polar grid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}
      [no marks,samples=201,smooth,domain=0:4]
      \addplot+ (4*180*x,x);
    \end{polaraxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Henri Menke, for this valuable work ! How can I remove the grid, if possible ?

Comment: @Cris `\begin{polaraxis}[axis lines=none,...`

Answer (score 12):

A MetaPost version of this spiral drawing, for whom it may interest. Included in  a LuaLaTeX program.

Edit : inspired by Thruston's solution, I've used the `dir` function instead of `rotated`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    u := .25cm; Rmax := 26; eps := 1;
    beginfig(1);
        % Polar grid
        label.top("$0$", origin);
        for t = 0 step 30 until 330:
            pair radius; radius = (Rmax+eps)*u * dir t;
            draw origin -- radius withcolor .8white;
            freelabel (decimal t, radius, origin);
        endfor;
        for j = 2 step 2 until Rmax:
            r := 2j*u; draw fullcircle scaled r withcolor .8white;
        endfor;
        for j = 4 step 4 until Rmax: label.top(decimal j, (j*u, 0)); endfor;
        % Spiral
        rad := pi/180*u;
        draw (origin for t = 1 upto 1440: .. t * dir t endfor) scaled rad withcolor blue;
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

PSTricks can solve it without hassle. One approach is as follows. Other approaches but with the same output are given in the last section.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=200}
\def\psvlabel#1{$\scriptstyle#1^\circ$}

\begin{document}

% r = f(Θ) in infix
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar](6,0)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi 2  mul}{x/3}
\end{pspicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

## The last section: Other approaches

For documentation purposes, let me introduce other approaches to produce the same output. Other parameters are intentionally omitted for the sake of simplicity.

```
% x = f(t) and y = g(t), both are in infix
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar](6,360)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi 2  mul}{t/3*cos(t)|t/3*sin(t)}
\end{pspicture}

% r = f(Θ) in postfix
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar](6,360)
    \psplot[polarplot,linecolor=red]{0}{360 2 mul}{x DegtoRad 3 div}
\end{pspicture}

% x = f(t) and y = g(t), both are in postfix
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar](6,360)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=red]{0}{360 2 mul}{t DegtoRad 3 div t PtoC}
\end{pspicture}
```

Even though domain can be specified in both radian and degree, I recommend using degree when the function is in postfix.

Comment: I intentionally changed the function from `r=Θ` to `r=Θ/3` to minimize the required space.

Answer (score 9):

Just for comparison, here is a generic Archimedes spiral in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) (wrapped up here in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en), so compile with `lualatex`).

[image: An Archimedes' Spiral with 8 turns]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric turns, radius;
    path ss;

    turns = 8;
    radius = 5cm;
    ss = (origin for t=1 upto 360 turns: -- dir t scaled t endfor) scaled (radius/turns/360);

    draw (left--right) scaled radius withcolor 1/2 white;
    draw (down--up)    scaled radius withcolor 1/2 white;

    drawarrow ss withcolor 2/3 blue;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should have thought myself to use `dir` instead of `rotated`…

Comment: @FranckPastor, I'm sorry to have posted a second MP solution - I had not seen yours when I did.